# NAudio code holds lock on input file

Tags: c#, .net, naudio

My code below holds a lock on the input file preventing me from working with it later:

```
public static void ToWave_WMF(string source, string destination)
{
    using (var reader = new MediaFoundationReader(source))
    using (var rateSampler = new MediaFoundationResampler(reader, new WaveFormat(DefaultEncoding.SampleRate, reader.WaveFormat.Channels)))
    using (var channelSampler = new MediaFoundationResampler(rateSampler, new WaveFormat(rateSampler.WaveFormat.SampleRate, DefaultEncoding.Channels)))
    {
        WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(destination, channelSampler);
    }
}

public static string BuildWavFile(string userFileLocation)
{
    var sampleList = new List<ISampleProvider>();
    try
    {
        // Add input file
        var waveFile = AudioHelpers.ToWave_WMF(userFileLocation);
        sampleList.Add(new AudioFileReader(waveFile));

        WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile16(sirenWaveFile, new ConcatenatingSampleProvider(sampleList));
    }
    finally
    {
        foreach (var sample in sampleList)
        {
            ((AudioFileReader)sample).Dispose();
        }
    }

    return sirenWaveFile;
}
```

Am I using resources wrong? Why is this lock being held? If I delete the file after `toWave_WMF()` there is no issue. If I use `sampleList.Add(new AudioFileReader(userFileLocation));` I also dont have any issues deleting the userFile.

Comment: Try wrapping this line: `sampleList.Add(new AudioFileReader(waveFile));` into a `using` block. `AudioFileReader` is a disposable item.

Comment: @Icemanind, does my try finally block not dispose them? I would use `using` but I actaly have a forloop before adding the `waveFile` to add a variable amount of other `audioFileReader` samples.